# UISlider - UISwitch-like mechanics

Tags: objective-c, algorithm

I am trying to use a UISlider like a UISwitch, because I can customize UISlider and stuff.
I am trying to imitate UISwitch mechanics perfectly.

Change on tap with a bit of tolerance, changing after you pass the middle point while dragging and stuff.

I've set up a UISlider, with my desired images, min 0 max 1, default 0, continuous property is OFF; fires up the method below on touch up inside.

I wrote the algorithm below, but there is just one thing that it doesn't work.
When you drag the knob from one end to the other end, it bounces back. ( 1.0 to 0.0 for example )

Can you please help me perfecting this?
Thanks!

Algorithm :

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        if ((slider.value >= 0.50 || slider.value == 0.0 || slider.value <= 0.10) && slider.value != 1.0) slider.value = 1.0;
        else if ((slider.value < 0.50 || slider.value == 1.0 || slider.value >= 0.90) && slider.value != 0.0) slider.value = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Comment: If you want to emulate a `UISwitch` “perfectly”, why not just use a `UISwitch`?  What is it about `UISwitch` that you want to change?

Answer (score 1):

The logic you are programming is telling it to "bounce back"

Dragging it from 1.0 to 0.0:

[slider value] = 0

you have said:
if value == 0 and value != 1 then set value to 1

same with your second logic path
if value == 1 and value != 0 then set the value to 0

```
- (void)sliderChanged:(UISlider *)slider {

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^{
        if (slider.value >= 0.50) 
           slider.value = 1.0;
        else if (slider.value < 0.50)
           slider.value = 0.0;
    }];
}
```

Also, why do you not want to use a UISwitch?

Answer (score 0):

I've been going through the UIKit and customizing everything for a few apps i've been working on. The solution I found to the UISwitch was to create your own based off of a  `UIControl`

From that point I handle the drag via

`- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

`- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

You can also implement a tap gesture to allow for tapping the switch just like the native switch.

I created my own based off of a UIControl as I felt I couldn't achieve that "native" snapping feel with a UISlider.